# htaccess ErrorDocument not rendering

Tags: apache, .htaccess, errordocument

i am trying to show an custom error message when a page is not found and on my .htaccess i added a line like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 error/404.html
```

but this just shows me 404.html on the screen instead rendering the 404.html page and if i write it like this

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error/404.html
```

than it gives me an error

> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Is there another way to do this to show the actual error html page ? Thank you, Daniel!

Comment: Explain: "shows me 404.html on the screen instead rendering the 404.html page"

Comment: What is your document root? The path should be relative to your document root. `URLs can begin with a slash (/) for local web-paths (relative to the DocumentRoot), or be a full URL which the client can resolve.` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument

Comment: on localhost on the folder "site" i have .htaccess and a subfolder "error" with the file "404.html" inside

when i request a page that is not in the folder "site", errordocument works but instead showing the content of the page "404.html", it just shows the browser write with the text 404.html on it.. actually the text is "error/404.html"

Comment: if i upload the content on the web, it works starting with a slash (/) but on localhost it doesnt work

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `ErrorDocument 404 /site/error/404.html`?

Comment: Ok I will post that as answer to help out future visitors on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your description it appears that your `error` folder is inside `DOCUMENT_ROOT/site` folder. In that case following full path `ErrorDocument` directive should work for you:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /site/error/404.html
```